# Putting Dates into Data Frame

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am scraping this website "https://www.sbp.org.pk/ecodata/index2.asp". Then with the below code, I scrape text and dates. Now I only want today's date.

```
        import datetime
        import requests
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        import pandas as pd
        from pandas import DataFrame
        import datetime as dt
        url = "https://www.sbp.org.pk/ecodata/index2.asp"
        r=requests.get(url)
        htmlContent = r.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, 'html.parser')
        
        now = datetime.datetime.today()
        
        data=[]
        for c in soup.find_all("td"):
            data.append(c.text.strip())
        data
        
        # here I am scraping the only dates from the text
        
        date_today = []
        for _ in data:
            try:
                data_date = dt.datetime.strptime(_, '%b %d, %Y')
                data3=data_date.date()
                print(data3)
                date_today.append(data_date.date())
            except ValueError:
                continue
        date_today
        
        for d in date_today:
            if d == now:
                df = pd.DataFrame({'abc':d})
                print (df)
            else:
                print("no update")
```

This is the code. The date_today variable contains dates. Now I only want today's date and then put it into data frame. The date_today is in the list form

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with how you were trying to initialize the `now` variable (it contained both date and time), you can simply use `date.today()` to get the current date, and also the part where you create your `DataFrame` (use list when using scalar values for columns).

The following code should work:-

```
from datetime import date
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime as dt

url = "https://www.sbp.org.pk/ecodata/index2.asp"
r=requests.get(url)
htmlContent = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, 'html.parser')

#get today's date        
now = date.today()
        
data=[]
for c in soup.find_all("td"):
    data.append(c.text.strip())
        
# here I am scraping the only dates from the text
        
date_today = []
for _ in data:
    try:
        data_date = dt.datetime.strptime(_, '%b %d, %Y')
        data3=data_date.date()
        #print(data3)
        date_today.append(data_date.date())
    except ValueError:
        continue

        
for d in date_today:
    if d == now:
        #use list when using scalar values for columns
        df = pd.DataFrame({'abc':[d]})
        print(df)
    else:
        print("no update")
```